# 3D-Animation from a table of data

Tags: plotting, animation

I'm a Mathematica newbie, so I hope this is not a very stupid question. I looked for an answer on the Internet, but unfortunatelly I didn't find anything proper.

I want make a little movie of a function $f(x,y,t)$. Because it takes loads of time to do the calculations for a nice looking plot, I decided to make a list plot instead of a common plot, which eliminates the jerking in the movie and makes it run more smoothly. This might come from calculating the points again and again every cycle (at least this would be my explanation for this improvement).

Until now I made a table of plots, which works fine, but because I want to make different movies with the same data, I think it would be smarter to make a table with the data and do only the plot several times, instead of calculating the values for each plot again and again. This is how I did it (I used the sine-function instead of my function):

```
ListAnimate[
  Table[
    Plot3D[Sin[(x + y) t], {x, 0, 5},{y, 0, 5}, 
      PlotRange -> {-1, 1}, PlotPoints -> 20], 
    {t, 0, 5}]]
```

Of course it is possible to make a table with `x`, `y`, `t` and `Sin[(x+y) t]`, but how can I tell the Plot3D function to do what I want?

I hope some of you can help me!

Comment: It is not quite clear what are you after since it works. I would only recommend separating making the list and animating it. That is, you make one statement: `lst=Table[Plot...,{t,0,5}]` and then a separate statement: `ListAnimate[lst]` which will play all this. Like this Mma will not spend time on calculating during the play. Further, you may want a more often changing the iterator. Say, `{t,0,5,0.05}`, rather than `{t,0,5}`. Together with the separated statements, it will make the animation to play smoothly.

Comment: Hi!
Thanks for your respond!

I already seperated the statement - but due to I still make a table of plots, I have to specify the plot-settings in my list (lst in your notation from above), which makes it necessary to calculate the whole table, e.g. when I want to use another ColorFunction.

What I want to make is to let Mathematica calculate f(x,y,t) for a certain amount of points (x,y,t) - you can see it as a "grid", and then in a second step I want to create an animation using this pre-calculated values for f.

I hope I could describe my problem more clearly.

Comment: You may do that, of course, as, for example, it is done in the answer of aardvark2012. This is not too much different from the `Plot3D` approach, however. In the end it also defines points. You may control this number by the option `PlotPoints`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you looking for

```
fdata = Table[
  Flatten[Table[{x, y, Sin[(x + y)*t]}, {x, 0, 5, 0.1}, {y, 0, 5, 0.1}], 1], 
{t, 0, 5, 0.2}];
```

where, of course, you would write in your own function, plot limits, increments, etc. As I understand it, this is the computationally intensive part. If it's *really* intensive, you'll probably want to save the data, by, for example

```
DumpSave["fata.mx", fdata];
```

Then you can always get it back with

```
<< fdata.mx
```

which will reassign the data to `fdata`.

Then either of

```
ListAnimate[ListPlot3D[# (*, insert all your settings here *)]& /@ fdata]
ListAnimate[ListPointPlot3D[# (*, insert all your settings here *)]& /@ fdata]
```

will give you your animations

[image]

[image]

I suspect that the jerkiness has more to do with the time increments than `Plot` vs `ListPlot`, but it's easy enough to switch between them and do some testing.

Comment: Thanks - that was exactly what I was looking for!

I guess "flatten" rearranges the table into something of a lower dimension (in this case it makes a row of (of course) dimension 1)?

Thank you very much!

Comment: @pcalc Glad I could help. Thanks for the accept. Actually, had I used just `Flatten[]` I would have got a 1D list of numbers. But we wanted a list of points `[{x1, y1}, {x2, y2},...}`, so I used `Flatten[..., 1]`